# QGIS: Status bar, scale drop down

Tags: qgis, scale, gui, scale-bar, interface

[image: QGIS status bar]

My scale drop down is very small in the status bar. While I can still input into it, I can't see what scale I'm currently at.

I've done a fresh install twice, but the same problem persists.

QGIS version 3.30.1

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to be a bug with the most recent version on my system. Installing a older version (v3.28.5) seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Worth reporting to on the QGIS bug tracker so it gets resolved going forward: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen